# Confusion with yield call to outer block

Tags: ruby

**CODE-I**

```
def sample
  x = "hi"
  puts " #{x}"
  x = yield
  puts " #{x}"
end
```

In the below code `block {}` from here => `sample {"hellooo"}` called
`yield` and assigned "hellooo" to `x`. Looks good and as expected.

```
sample{'helloo'}
# >>  hi
# >>  helloo
```

**CODE-II**

```
o = Object.new
def o.each
  x = yield
  p x
  x = yield
  p x
  x = yield
  p x
end
e = o.to_enum # => #<Enumerator: #<Object:0x007fd1d20494e8>:each>
```

**Why the same not happened in the below call with `e.next "sample"`, as the p didn't printed anything?**

```
e.next {"sample"} # => nil
e.next # => nil
# >> nil
```

**EDIT** (Here how `enum#feed` did the change with the help of `yield`?)

```
o = Object.new
=> #<Object:0x2299d88>
def o.each
x = yield         
p x       
x = yield
p x 
x = yield
p x 
end
=> nil
e=o.to_enum
=> #<Enumerator: #<Object:0x2299d88>:each>
e.next
=> nil
e.feed "hi"
=> nil
e.next
"hi"
=> nil
```

Comment: Please, when posting code, make extra effort to ensure reader's comfort. It's in your best interests. Original code was unreadable IRB mess.

Comment: You get nil? Cause I get an infinite wait and an IRB hang.

Comment: @Linuxios Yes, What I got from `IRB` pasted here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I will remember! Sorry as what you did the work,what i supposed to do.

Comment: #next returns the next iteration of the enumerator only, it doesn't take a parameter or block.  It also doesn't inject a value into the enumerator.

Comment: If you need an object that exhibits different behavior to a method call based on its internal state and parameters to the call, use a Fiber.

Comment: @Catnapper I was just playing with `yield` behavior, By theory `yield` should call the outsider block with a method. And it also didn't causes an error,that means `yield` has been called. but somehow variable `x` is not being assigned to the value as `sample`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next` does not take a block. So if you pass it one, it simply ignores it.

It is not possible to simulate something being returned from the block when using the `next` method of an enumerator. When using an `to_enum`, the block given to the `each` method will always return `nil` except if a value has previously supplied by the `feed` method.

Comment: yes! what you are saying that has been visible from the output,but my question is how has been prevented with `next` only?

Comment: @DoLoveSky Nothing is being prevented. The enumerator simply does not return anything from the block.

Comment: @DoLoveSky I'm not quite sure what you mean by "Here how enum#feed did the change with the help of yield?". If you mean "how is feed implemented?": I imagine it simply sets an instance variable on the enumerable, which is then returned from the block (and subsequently cleared) the next time `next` is called.

Comment: Okay,let me put my question - with `feed` the `yield` is called and in turn `yield` sets the value to `x`, which is being printed out by `e.next`. Where the same is not being performed by the `e.next {"sample"}`, where `yield` was called but nothing set to x. the way i am thinking might be wrong, but it is my confusion.

Comment: @DoLoveSky First `yield` is called, which transfers control to `next` which returns the value that was yielded - in this case `nil` because nothing was yielded. `yield` then waits for the block to return. That happens the next time you call `next`. The value that was returned by the block will be stored in `x`. By default `next` does not return anything from the block, so `x` is `nil`. If you call `feed` with a value before calling `next`, `next` will return that value from the block.

Comment: In the [doc](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Enumerator/feed) saying that first `next` called,then `yield`. I am really confusing at all. Could you please explain it from the basic root?

Comment: @DoLoveSky Yes, sorry, my explanation started with step 2 of the example in the docs. The first time you call `next`, `each` executes until `yield` is called. At that point control returns to `next`, which returns the value that was yielded... and so on.

Comment: If you don't mind could you explain the these `next-yield` cycle ,with visualizations of codes?